Spatial Partitioning: Strategy for obtaining current room (x,y,w,h) given a position (x,y)
In my game, dungeons are represented by rooms and hallways, both defined like this:
struct room{
    int id; // incremental Id given in order of creation
    int x,y,w,h; // coordinates and dimensions
};

At any time, the player will be in some room or hallway. My goal is to figure out which room they are in only given their position.
I would like to find a way to do this that doesn't involve an O(n) solution. Is there a data structure that is fine tuned for a task such as this?

What have you considered so far? Do you know about quadtrees? They’re the obvious generic solution to this, unless you have more specific requirements.
